# react-router official example Jump to three pages failed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is an official example of [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config)

I want to click on `Cart` to jump to `/tacos/cart/abc`  But it failed，What should I do?

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

// Some folks find value in a centralized route config.
// A route config is just data. React is great at mapping
// data into components, and <Route> is a component.

// Our route config is just an array of logical "routes"
// with `path` and `component` props, ordered the same
// way you'd do inside a `<Switch>`.
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/sandwiches",
    component: Sandwiches
  },
  {
    path: "/tacos",
    component: Tacos,
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/tacos/bus",
        component: Bus
      },
      {
        path: "/tacos/cart",
        component: Cart
      },
      {
        path: "/tacos/cart/abc",
        component: Abc
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function RouteConfigExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/tacos">Tacos</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/sandwiches">Sandwiches</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route, i) => (
            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

// A special wrapper for <Route> that knows how to
// handle "sub"-routes by passing them in a `routes`
// prop to the component it renders.
function RouteWithSubRoutes(route) {
  return (
    <Route
      path={route.path}
      render={props => (
        // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
        <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />
      )}
    />
  );
}

function Sandwiches() {
  return <h2>Sandwiches</h2>;
}

function Tacos({ routes }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Tacos</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/tacos/bus">Bus</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/tacos/cart">Cart</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, i) => (
          <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

function Bus() {
  return <h3>Bus</h3>;
}

function Cart() {
  return <Link to="/tacos/cart/abc">Cart</Link>;
}

function Abc() {
  return <h3>abc</h3>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `Switch` component matches and returns the ***first*** matching `Route` or `Redirect`. Your `"/tacos/cart/abc" path is rendered ***after*** the less specific "/tacos/cart" path. "/tacos/cart" is a prefix of all "/tacos/cart/XXX" paths.

```
routes: [
  {
    path: "/tacos/bus",
    component: Bus
  },
  {
    path: "/tacos/cart", // <-- prefix to "/tacos/cart/abc", will match first
    component: Cart
  },
  {
    path: "/tacos/cart/abc",
    component: Abc
  }
]

...

<Switch>
  {routes.map((route, i) => (
    <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
  ))}
</Switch>
```

## Solution

Reorder your routes that are rendered into the `Switch` to define more specific paths before less specific paths.

```
routes: [
  {
    path: "/tacos/bus",
    component: Bus
  },
  {
    path: "/tacos/cart/abc", // <-- more specific "/tacos/cart" path 
    component: Abc
  },
  {
    path: "/tacos/cart", // <-- less specific "/tacos/cart" path
    component: Cart
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It has been settled